# Multiple display of vector layer in a QGIS plugin interface

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, display, interface

```
def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    icon_path = ':/plugins/cropEt/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'links crop et'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

     # connect our select function to the canvasClicked signal
    result = self.clickTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.selectFeature)
    QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "connect = %s"%str(result) )


def unload(self):
    """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
    for action in self.actions:
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(
            self.tr(u'&Testlink'),
            action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
    # remove the toolbar
    del self.toolbar

def handleMouseDown(self, point, button):
    #QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "X,Y = %s,%s" % (str(point.x()),str(point.y())) )
    self.dlg.clearTextBrowser()
    self.dlg.setTextBrowser( str(point.x()) + " , " +str(point.y()) )


def selectFeature(self, point, button):
    layer = self.iface.addVectorLayer("D:/python/cropped_area.shp", "sample_cropped area","ogr")
    selectList = []
    if layer:
        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
            # fetch geometry
                geom = feature.geometry()
                print "Feature ID %d: " % feature.id()
                layer.setSelectedFeatures(selectList)
           # show some information about the feature
            #if geom.type() == QGis.Point:
                #x = geom.asPoint()
                #print "Point: " + str(x)
            #elif geom.type() == QGis.Line:
             #   x = geom.asPolyline()
              #  print "Line: %d points" % len(x)
                #if geom.type() == QGis.Polygon:
                    #x = geom.asPolygon()
                    #numPts = 0
                #for ring in x:
                    #numPts += len(ring)
                    #print "Polygon: %d rings with %d points" % (len(x), numPts)
                #else:
                    #print "Unknown"

            # fetch attributes
                attrs = feature.attributes()
                #if attrs==row[0].strip():
                #selection.append(feature.id())
   # attrs is a list. It contains all the attribute values of this feature
                print attrs
                #layer.setSelectedFeatures(selection)
    if not layer:
        print "Layer failed to load!" 

    QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "Click on the feature to select" )


    #else:
           # QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "No layer currently selected in TOC" )
```

I want to load a shapefile and want to display the properties like feature count, attribute table list in QGIS interface plugin.  Accordingly wrote the code; a portion is attached... But, on each mouse click, a new layer is getting created and no feature property is displayed even after removing the commented statements.

Can anyone suggest the error?

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is in this line:

```
layer = self.iface.addVectorLayer("D:/python/cropped_area.shp", "sample_cropped area","ogr")
```

The layer is added anew each time selectFeature is fired.

You'd rather want to add the layer once (e.g. in the `__init__` or `initGui` function), and save it to a member of your plugin object (e.g. `self.layer=addVectorLayer(…)`) so you can refer to it in `selectFeature`.

The whole code might look similar to this:

```
def initGui(self): """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    icon_path = ':/plugins/cropEt/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'links crop et'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())


    # LOAD YOUR LAYER HERE
    self.layer=self.iface.addVectorLayer("D:/python/cropped_area.shp", "sample_cropped area","ogr")


    # connect our select function to the canvasClicked signal
    result = self.clickTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.selectFeature)
    QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "connect = %s"%str(result) )


def unload(self):
    """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
    for action in self.actions:
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(
            self.tr(u'&Testlink'),
            action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
    # remove the toolbar
    del self.toolbar

def handleMouseDown(self, point, button):
    #QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "X,Y = %s,%s" % (str(point.x()),str(point.y())) )
    self.dlg.clearTextBrowser()
    self.dlg.setTextBrowser( str(point.x()) + " , " +str(point.y()) )


def selectFeature(self, point, button):
    layer = self.layer # USE THE STORED REFERENCE TO YOUR LAYER HERE
    selectList = []
    if layer:
        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
            # fetch geometry
                geom = feature.geometry()
                print "Feature ID %d: " % feature.id()
                layer.setSelectedFeatures(selectList)
           # show some information about the feature
            #if geom.type() == QGis.Point:
                #x = geom.asPoint()
                #print "Point: " + str(x)
            #elif geom.type() == QGis.Line:
             #   x = geom.asPolyline()
              #  print "Line: %d points" % len(x)
                #if geom.type() == QGis.Polygon:
                    #x = geom.asPolygon()
                    #numPts = 0
                #for ring in x:
                    #numPts += len(ring)
                    #print "Polygon: %d rings with %d points" % (len(x), numPts)
                #else:
                    #print "Unknown"

            # fetch attributes
                attrs = feature.attributes()
                #if attrs==row[0].strip():
                #selection.append(feature.id())
   # attrs is a list. It contains all the attribute values of this feature
                print attrs
                #layer.setSelectedFeatures(selection)
    if not layer:
        print "Layer failed to load!" 

    QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "Click on the feature to select" )


    #else:
           # QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "No layer currently selected in TOC" )
```

Comment: Thank you @christoph ..It worked as expected. Now, the problem is  how to select a particular feature within the polygon with a single click.Any idea?

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact: in `selectFeature` you call `layer.setSelectedFeatures(selectList)` while `selectList` is an empty list … 
I can't tell from your code exactly what the values of the function arguments `point`and `button` would be, but you'd have to do something along the lines of:
`if geom.intersects(point): selectList.append(feature);` (<http://qgis.org/api/2.8/classQgsGeometry.html>). (possibly before that projecting the point to the layers reference system)